# Calling compiled C from R with .C()

Tags: c, r

I'm trying to call a program (function `getNBDensities` in the C executable `measurementDensities_out`) from R. The function is passed several arrays and the variable `double runsum`. Right now, the `getNBDensities` function basically does nothing: it prints to screen the values of passed parameters. My problem is the syntax of calling the function:

```
array(.C("getNBDensities",
            hr = as.double(hosp.rate), # a vector (s x 1)
            sp = as.double(samplingProbabilities), # another vector (s x 1)
            odh = as.double(odh), # another vector (s x 1)
            simCases = as.integer(x[c("xC1","xC2","xC3")]), # another vector (s x 1)
            obsCases = as.integer(y[c("yC1","yC2","yC3")]), # another vector (s x 1)
            runsum = as.double(runsum), # double
            DUP = TRUE, NAOK = TRUE, PACKAGE = "measurementDensities_out")$f,
            dim = length(y[c("yC1","yC2","yC3")]),
            dimnames = c("yC1","yC2","yC3"))
```

The error I get, after proper execution of the function (i.e., the right output is printed to screen), is

```
Error in dim(data) <- dim : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

I'm unclear what the dimensions are that I should be passing the function: should it be `s` x 5 + 1 (five vectors of length `s` and one double)? I've tried all sorts of combinations (including `s`x5+1) and have found only seemingly conflicting descriptions/examples online of what's supposed to happen here.

For those who are interested, the C code is below:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <R_ext/PrtUtil.h>
#define NUM_STRAINS 3
#define DEBUG
void getNBDensities(  double *hr, double *sp, double *odh, int *simCases, int *obsCases, double *runsum );
void getNBDensities( double *hr, double *sp, double *odh, int *simCases, int *obsCases, double *runsum ) {
#ifdef DEBUG
  for ( int s = 0; s < NUM_STRAINS; s++ ) {
    Rprintf("\nFor strain %d",s); 
    Rprintf("\n\tHospitalization rate = %lg", hr[s]);
    Rprintf("\n\tSimulation probability = %lg",sp[s]);
    Rprintf("\n\tSimulated cases = %d",simCases[s]);
    Rprintf("\n\tObserved cases = %d",obsCases[s]);
    Rprintf("\n\tOverdispersion parameter = %lg",odh[s]);
}
  Rprintf("\nRunning sum = %lg",runsum[0]);
#endif
}
```

---

**naive solution**

While better (i.e., potentially faster or syntactically clearer) solutions may exist (see Dirk's answer below), the following simplification of the code works:

```
     out<-.C("getNBDensities",
            hr = as.double(hosp.rate),
            sp = as.double(samplingProbabilities),
            odh = as.double(odh),
            simCases = as.integer(x[c("xC1","xC2","xC3")]),
            obsCases = as.integer(y[c("yC1","yC2","yC3")]),
            runsum = as.double(runsum))
```

The variables can be accessed in `>out`.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, so why are you trying to turn nothing into an array?

Comment: @hadley: You're honing in on the issue, I think. I was working from the example of another C function that I call in my code, and which does manipulate a large array. This function will ultimately only read from the arrays to calculate `runsum`, which the rest of my R program will then use. Calling just `out<-(.C("getNBDensities",...))`, however, just returns `NULL` for `out`...

Comment: I would always recommend `.Call()` over `.C()`.

Comment: My code actually already uses a `.C()` call someplace else. When I used `Rprof`, rather than `.C()`, `.Call()` showed up near the top--I figured this meant it had been optimized internally. Bottom line is that I'm pretty terrible with syntax, and I'm worried I won't be able to rewrite my other function call using `.Call()` if I can't even master a simple `.C()` call here.

Comment: Historically, `.C()` came first. But it is also *much more limited* in what it can do.  Most sane folks recommend `.Call()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look into the [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) package which makes compiling, linking and loading of C, C++ or Fortran code an absolute breeze.

That said, and particularly if C++ is another option for you, also look at the [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) package which permits you transfer both R and C++ objects back and forth with ease.

Comment: This is supposed to be a very small and fast function (it's just calculating the sum of negative binomial densities for three samples), so C++ is overkill; as I wrote, I'm also calling compiled C someplace else. I will look into `inline` if I can't figure this out and for future projects--thank you for the reference.

Comment: Rcpp helps not only for *code that runs faster* but IMNSHO for *code that gets written faster* because it removes a lot of the cobwebs of the C API.  Have a look, and questions usually get a friendly answer on the `rcpp-devel` list.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out. I prefer C++. However, this  program (an implementation of the R package `pomp`) is already written--my goal is just to improve the runtime. For future projects, the small hurdle of learning Rcpp will certainly be worth it.